# Row locking in recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) says:

> The locking clauses cannot be used in contexts where returned rows cannot be clearly identified with individual table rows; for example they cannot be used with aggregation.

How do I work around this in the setting of a recursive query, that is implemented with `UNION (ALL)`?

Is there a better solution than joining the result of the recursive query with the table again, this time with `FOR UPDATE`? I would have to lock the whole table for this query to make sure that nothing changes concurrently to the join, right?

Comment: What makes you think that aggregation has anything to do with a recursive query?

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that aggregation has anything to do with a recursive query? Seems to work for me,

```
CREATE TABLE foo(pk,fk,description)
AS VALUES
    ( 1 , null , 'domains' ),
    ( 2 , 1 , 'people' ),
    ( 3 , 1 , 'cars' ),
    ( 4 , 2 , 'tom' ),
    ( 5 , 2 , 'smith' ),
    ( 6 , 3 , 'vmw' ),
    ( 7 , 2 , 'betty' ),
    ( 8 , 3 , 'ford' );

WITH RECURSIVE t(pk, fk, description, level) AS (
    SELECT pk, fk, ARRAY[description], 0
    FROM foo
    WHERE fk IS NULL
    UNION ALL
        SELECT foo.pk, foo.fk, t.description || foo.description, t.level+1
        FROM t
        JOIN foo ON (foo.fk = t.pk)
)
SELECT *
FROM t
FOR UPDATE;
```

[*Example taken from example on this question on dba.se*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190428/is-a-self-defining-table-of-domains-normalized/190443#190443)

Comment: `WITH RECURSIVE` contains a `UNION ALL` doesn't it? ;) Won't there be a race condition in your example when foo is altered during the recursive query? The rows are locked only after the `SELECT FROM t` ran, right? I need the rows to be locked as soon as they are encountered in the recursive query.

Comment: You don't know what rows you're going to visit until you do the recursion. As you're doing the recursion the rows are added to the output result set and locked. Just like anything with `READ COMMITTED` and `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`

Comment: You might be right, but can you cite any source to prove your claim? I would believe that the rows are locked *after* the result set is complete and not as soon as they are added. Following [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) I understand that the "outer" select runs somewhat concurrently to the recursive CTE, but I'd like to be sure that the locking happens immediately as soon as a row is visited.

Comment: "but I'd like to be sure that the locking happens immediately as soon as a row is visited." if you're asking a database-internals question then my guess is you'll have to to rewrite a **totally new** question asking when the actual locking happens. As such, I'm not going to dive through the source to figure that out. My assumption is the rows returned are locked immediately, but I can see that being a complex issue covering cases like index-only scans and the like.

Comment: Of cause I don't expect you to dig through the source code only to answer my question. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: No need to look at the source - the execution plan is enough. The rows will be locked *after* the recursive query is done. Have you tried using `FOR UPDATE` inside the CTE?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe No, when I run the above query with `EXPLAIN` (even `VERBOSE`), I get no information when or even if any locking occurs. And no, "ERROR: FOR UPDATE/SHARE in a recursive query is not implemented" (which is why I'm asking this question).

Comment: I see. Still, locking happens in the end - you should see a `LockRows` node. You don't see that because your query locks nothing (try `FOR UPDATE OF t` to see why). I don't think you can do better than locking the result by joining with the original table in the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe No, unfortunately not. `FOR UPDATE of t`: "ERROR: FOR UPDATE cannot be applied to a WITH query". `FOR UPDATE of foo`: "ERROR: relation "foo" in FOR UPDATE clause not found in FROM clause". A join may be the best I can get, but it is unsatisfying as there is a moment where the result of the query is ready but the rows are not locked yet.

Comment: That's what I meant: you cannot lock the rows from the CTE. The error you get with `OF t` makes that clear. Without the `OF t` the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` just tacitly locks *nothing*, and that's why you didn't see a lock in the execution plan. Yes, it's unfortunate, but you can't avoid the race condition. Maybe an *advisory lock* can help.